# Use space in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

I want to run this:

```
java -jar C:\Users\Me\Desktop\example.jar @C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My Folder\text.txt
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: C:\User\Me\Desktop\My (Access denied)
```

Obviously, the problem is the space ("My Folder"). How can I fix this?

Comment: Try quoting it: `"@C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My Folder\text.txt"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use double quotes

> java -jar "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\example.jar" "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My
>   Folder\text.txt"